# Container can no longer identify other containers in same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

Docker version: 4.14.1
Docker container types: Windows
Docker compose version: 2.3

Since yesterday, my containers specified in my docker-compose file, can no longer do DNS lookups based on the name of other containers. This is a sudden error between all my projects, that was working just fine yesterday. 
I can still connect using a direct IP to other containers, but this is unwanted.

I am really not sure what have changed.
I have tried resetting, restarting etc.

I have used Docker for some time, but would not say I am a pro.
Do you have any feedback on how i can diagnose this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It helped defining a specific network in docker-compose file instead of relying on the default one.